# How to convert raw input into index value in R

Tags: r, dictionary, text-mining

Thanks for help first.
I have a raw input file "`foo.txt`", and another `dictionary` file "`dic.csv`", where each row in dic file is a `key-value` pair, the key is one character and the value is another character.

maybe like this, **foo.txt**:

```
abcd
dcba
aaaa
```

and **dic.csv**:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
```

I want to convert the "foo.txt" to the values in the dic file according to the key they matched, such that in result of:

```
1234
4321
1111
```

Are there any efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
chartr(paste(d1$Col1, collapse=''), paste(d1$Col2, collapse=""), v1)
#[1] "1234" "4321" "1111"
```

Or instead of using two `paste`, we can loop over with `sapply`

```
v2 <- sapply(d1, paste, collapse='')
chartr(v2[1], v2[2], v1)
#[1] "1234" "4321" "1111"
```

Or using `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
mgsub(d1$Col1, d1$Col2, v1)
#[1] "1234" "4321" "1111"
```

Or

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('[abcd]', list(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4), v1)
#[1] "1234" "4321" "1111"
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c('abcd', 'dcba', 'aaaa')
 d1 <- data.frame(Col1= letters[1:4], Col2=1:4, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: It works. However, due to my carelessness, I didn't describe my question very well. Because when I apply it to a large `d1` data ( 6000+ rows but also 2 cols ), it fails and returns the error `'old' is longer than 'new'`. These codes may lack generalization ability

Comment: @SummerR.L  My code was based on what you showed in the example.  You may have to show a small example where it fails.  I also assume that your key/value pair is unique.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I checked carefully and it seemed it was some encoding problems that caused it fail. I re-pick your answer as the best. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn your dictionary `data.frame` into a named vector and then use indexing:

```
foo <- c("abcd", "dcba", "aaaa")
dict <- data.frame(key = letters[1:4], value = 1:4)
dict.vec <- setNames(dict$value, dict$key)

sapply(foo, function(x) 
    paste(dict.vec[strsplit(x, "")[[1]]], collapse = ""))
#   abcd   dcba   aaaa 
# "1234" "4321" "1111"
```